# Efficient algorithm to find number of factors

Tags: factoring

Given an integer n, is there an efficient algorithm to find the number of factors of n?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3820/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-number-of-prime-factors-of-a-given-integer

Comment: Thank you. So I shouldn't expect there would be such an algorithm.